# XQuery and BaseX- How to store the output to a combobox?

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

I am using BaseX as backend to store XML Files. Front end is in Java. I want to populate
certain elements data into a combobox. The output of the XQuery is string. I am facing problem to load this string in a combobox. Below is the XML file-

```
<Cities>
  <City><C>London</C></City>
  <City><C>New Delhi</C></City>
  <City><C>Mumbai</C></City>
  <City><C>Moscow</C></City>
  <City><C>Tokyo</C></City>
  <City><C>Mumbai</C></City>
  <City><C>Tokyo</C></City>
  <City><C>Mumbai</C></City>
  <City><C>Tokyo</C></City>
  <City><C>Mumbai</C></City>
  <City><C>New Delhi</C></City>
</Cities>
```

Using this XML file, I want to populate all the distinct cities in a combobox. This will be done by following XQuery-

```
for $x in distinct-values(doc("City")/Cities/City/C)
  return $x
```

The output of this is a simple string -

```
`London New Delhi Mumbai Moscow Tokyo`
```

There are 5 cities resulting from the query. 
How can I populate this in a combobox..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
element select {
  distinct-values(doc("City")/Cities/City/C) ! element option { . }
}
```